# Serving Json from WCF Service with no extension in IIS

Tags: json, iis, browser, wcf

I have a WCF service set up to serve data through multiple endpoints (SOAP, JSON and XML) the SOAP and XML is working perfect, but when I try to view the json I get a prompt to download a file with the json results instead of displaying the results in the browser.  This probably won't matter as the client will most likely be consuming the data from some sort of .net environment which will be able to handle the response natively, but I wanted to see if there was a way to display the json results in the browser just like the XML results.

An example of the url I am using to get the results:
http://localhost/api/Service.svc/json/GetResults?name=Test&test=test

This then prompts me to download a file named "GetReults" with no extension and the filetype is: application/json

Comment: I think it is default behavior how browser handle application\json mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to view the content of the json response in the browser then change your settings in Firefox or else use another browser. I have tried a similar thing with IE and it showed the json content in the browser without making any changes. Not sure what Chrome will do.

I have a similar situation with a rest call that I post a request to. I was making a mock rest service in Grails and noticed that when I hit the live server or my mock server with Firefox it kept asking me to download the file, but not with IE. The problem I'm dealing with now is that I am trying to hit my mock endpoint with SoapUI and it is also asking me to download the file. If I hit the live server with SoapUI it does not ask me to download the file.

Still trying to figure this issue out.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the desired behavior. The return response's content type is "application/json". Most browsers cannot display content with this content type inline (unless manually configured), so they prompt you to download the file.

If you actually save this file, and open it with -- say, note Notepad -- you will notice that the pure JSON response is contained in the file.

The inability to handle this content type and the browser forcing this download is almost never an issue, however. The reason is, the general use case for the usage of this JSON endpoint is either the ASP.NET AJAX framework-powered webpages (that automagically make these requests and parse responses by themselves), scripting environments like Python or Perl (which again would just get the requests and then parse them), or custom JavaScript frameworks.

Hope this helps!